# Understanding $\langle a,b \mid bab^{-1}=a^2\rangle$ as a semidirect product.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, semidirect-product

I gave myself the exercise of determining
$$\langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}=b^{-1}\rangle$$
which appears in nature as the fundamental group for the klein bottle (deduced from van kampen's theorem.)
One way to understand this is as the semidirect product $\mathbb Z \ltimes_{\phi} \mathbb Z$

where conjugation by an element in $\mathbb Z$ acts on $\mathbb Z$ by
$\phi_n(m):=(-1)^n(m)$.

I received an assignment to prove some basic properties of $\langle a,b \mid bab^{-1}=a^2\rangle$ including a faithful matrix representation. However, upon doing some calculations I realized what I was doingg was the same as before: studying the action of conjugation by an element.

On one hand, it is clear from $aba^{-1}=b^2$ that the action of some $n \in \mathbb N$ should be something like multiplication by $2$. However, in trying to determine $a^{-1}b a$ I needed some division by $2$, which led me to believe that the action I should be considering is more like
$$\mathbb Z  \to_{\phi} \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}])$$
 where $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}]$ is the additive group of $2$-adics. The action seems to be $\phi_n(m):=2^{n}(m)$.

**Question 0:** Does everything so far make sense?

Furthermore, in my problem, I was given two generators that map to $GL(2,\mathbb R)$.

**Question 1:** would it be more natural to study the action on $\mathbb R^4$? In particular, this would not be an irreducible representation, but we could have something like

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 &2 & 0\\
0 & 1&0&2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0& 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\mathbb Z$ embeds into the upper left quadrant, and $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ into the bottom right?

**Question 2.1:** Looking at this matrix got me wondering: how do elements of $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ look like as elements in the presentation $<a,b>$, I can't actually identify this with a subgroup, and how can I prove normality and that there actually is a subgroup that looks like $\mathbb Z[1/2]$?

Comment: Question title and body do not match.

Comment: @KennyLau thanks. The question devolved a bit as I was writing.

Comment: Good intuition about $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try and show that the homomorphism from your group $G$ to $GL_2(\Bbb{Q})$ given by
$$
b\mapsto \pmatrix{2&0\cr0&1\cr},\qquad a\mapsto \pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}
$$
is injective. The image of that homomorphism is the group
$$
\Gamma=\left\{\pmatrix{x&y\cr0&1\cr}\bigg\vert\ x=2^n, y=m/2^k, m,n,k\in\Bbb{Z}\right\}.
$$
The subgroup $N$ consisting of the elements of $\Gamma$ with $x=1$ is clearly normal. It is the image of the group generated by conjugates of $a$.
A mildly unusual thing is that $a$ is conjugate to its "square root". By that I mean the element
$$
a^{1/2}:=b^{-1}ab.
$$
After all,
$$
a^{1/2}a^{1/2}=b^{-1}abb^{-1}ab=b^{-1}a^2b=a.
$$
We also have
$$a^{1/4}:=b^{-2}ab^2,$$
as
$$
a^{1/4}a^{1/4}=b^{-2}a^2b^2=b^{-1}(b^{-1}a^2b)b=b^{-1}ab=a^{1/2}.
$$
I haven't checked everything, but it sure looks like we can go on indefinitely.
$$
N=\langle a, a^{1/2},a^{1/4},a^{1/8},\ldots\rangle\unlhd G,
$$
and then if you can show that $G=N\rtimes \langle b\rangle$ you are done, I think.

Comment: To show that the representation is faithful, I think that it is sufficient to observe that every element of the group can be written as $b^{-i}a^kb^j$. From this, one can check that this element gets sent to $x=2^j$ and $y=k/s^{i}$ if I'm not messing up any of the arithmetic. I very much like the second half of your answer, it is very instructive, thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan @Andres. My post is not too coherent, but I think the general approach works.

Comment: I was incorrect before, here is the actual solution:  the image is of the  form $$\begin{pmatrix}2^j/2^{i} & k/2^{i}\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
where the integers here are intended to reflect the powers of a general element $b^{-i}a^kb^j $. From this, we can check that the representation is faithful (homomorphism is injective) by considering the kernel. If this were the identity homomorphism, that would require that $2^j/2^i=1$, so that $j=i$, and if $k/2^i=0$, then $k=0$, but if $j=i$, then the element was originally trivial, showing that the map is a monomorphism.